# Killing A Process Using Htop Question

Tags: htop

I'm a college student and some sites are blocked here so I use a VPN to fix that problem. So my question is: I have to run the command as root to connect to the VPN and when I'm done just closing the terminal will not kill the process (disconnect me from the VPN service). I ran this in a new terminal:

```
kill -9 2904
```

(2904 is the PID)

But nothing happened.

I am able to terminate all other processes other than this one. Am I missing something here?

Comment: You probably will need to list the processes connected to 2904 (`ps ef| grep 2904` will show this process)

Comment: Would you like me to post what I get? Maybe you can make something of it. Its beyond my understanding at this point. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I asked this on another forum and was given a great answer that worked perfectly.

```
sudo kill -9 <PID>
```